# Login problem with Android browser and Google OpenID

Tags: support, openid

I can't log in to Stack Overflow using my existing OpenID from the browser on my Android phone.

I have an OpenID through Google, which I use to log in to Stack Overflow and related sites. I just used the ID to create a Meta Stack Overflow login. However, it doesn't work from my Android browser.

Here is what happens: I click the Google icon on the Stack Overflow login page, and what appears to be the correct URL is entered into the box below the provider icons. I click the login button, but I am taken to a page that says "Your OpenID does not have an account on Stack Overflow yet." The button below the message offers to confirm and create a new account.

I don't want to create a new Stack Overflow account--I want to log into my existing account from my Android phone. How would I do that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem turned out to be with the google OpenID. I changed my ID to the following:

```
http://www.google.com/profiles/<my Google account user name>
```

That solved the problem. I can enter that into the login page "Enter your OpenID manually" filed on both my desktop and Android browsers and I am logged in without problem.

Comment: you can also simply enter "gmail.com" or "username@gmail.com"